# Weak convergence of unit mass

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

I have found in my notes the statement bellow:

> $\mu_n\Rightarrow\mu$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, if and only if $x_n\rightarrow x$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ where $\mu$ is the unit mass at $x$ and $\mu_n$ is a unit mass at $x_n$ for $n=1,2,...$.

I do not understand this statement clearly as why this holds.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ are probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$

The definition of $\mu_n \Rightarrow \mu$ is that $\int f \,d\mu_n \to \int f \,d\mu$ for all bounded continuous functions $f$.  If $\mu_n$ is a point mass at $x_n$ and $\mu$ is a point mass at $x$, then the above condition says that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ for all bounded continuous functions $x$.  So you need to prove that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ for all bounded continuous $f$ if and only if $x_n \to x$.

In one direction, if $x_n \to x$, then it simply follows from (one of) the definition(s) of continuity that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ whenever $f$ is continuous.  The other direction is a bit trickier.  Suppose that $x_n$ does not converge to $x$.  Then there is a positive distance $\epsilon$ such that $|x_n - x| > \epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$.  Now let $f$ be a continuous function such that $f(x) = 1$ but $f(y) = 0$ whenever $|y-x| > \epsilon$ (I will leave it to you to figure out what such a function looks like).  Then $f(x) = 1$ but $f(x_n) = 0$ for infinitely many $n$, so $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(x)$.

Comment: Why is the function $f$ you constructed continuous?

Comment: @NicholasRoberts I didn't construct it.  I'm simply claiming the following: for any $\epsilon>0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a continuous function $f$ such that $f(x) = 1$ and $f(y) = 0$ whenever $|y-x|>\epsilon$.  If you draw a picture then it will be easy to see how to construct such an $f$.

Comment: What would be the different, if we assume $\mu$ is the unit mass?

Comment: @statwoman We are assuming that $\mu$ is a unit mass at the point $x$

Comment: Oh ok. I'm assuming you just extend the function linearly inbetween 0 and 1?

Comment: @NicholasRoberts Yes