# $x_n\to x$ in a metric space if and only if the Dirac measures $\delta_{x_n}$ converge weakly to $\delta_x$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $E$ be a metric space and $\delta_x$ denote the Dirac measure concentrated on $x$ for $x\in E$.

> Now let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq E$ and $x\in E$. I would like to show that
>
> 1. $x_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}x$ in $E$;
> 2. $\delta_{x_n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\delta_x$ weakly$^1$
>
> are equivalent. In a second step, I would like to show that if $\delta_{x_n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\mu$ for some probability measure $\mu$ on $E$, then $\mu=\delta_z$ for some $z\in E$.

(1.) implies (2.) is a triviality, but I'm not sure how to conclude the other implication.

Assume (2.). It's not enough to conclude, but we may observe the following: Assume $$x_{n_k}\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}y\tag2$$ for some increasing $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ and some $y\in E\setminus\{x\}$. Then, since $C_b(E)$ is separating, there is a $f\in C_b(E)$ with $f(x)\ne f(y)$. But now, since $f$ is continuous and $(1)$, $$f(y)=\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{n_k})=\lim_{k\to\infty}=\delta_{x_{n_k}}=\delta_xf=f(x)\tag3;$$ in condradiction to $x\ne y$.

> So, how can we prove that (2.) implies (1.) and what do we need to do, to show the second step?
> $^1$ i.e. $$\delta_{x_n}f=f(x_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}f(x)=\delta_x(f)\tag1\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in C_b(E).$$

Comment: Just out of pure curiosity, what is the definition of weak convergence of a sequence of measures? It's it that given any open set $U\subseteq E$, the sequence $\delta_{x_n}(U)$ converges to $\delta_x(U)$?

Comment: See a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3911638/weak-convergence-of-unit-mass/3911669?noredirect=1#comment8067532_3911669

Comment: Have you try the function $f(y)= 1\wedge d_E(y,x)$ ?

Comment: @Arthur The definition is $(1)$. For a general sequence of measures $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and a measure $\mu$ it is $\mu_nf\to\mu f$.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen Ah, that might work for the other implication. Do you have an idea for the second step as well?

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen No, I meant the claim that if generally $(\delta_x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges weakly, then the weak limit $\mu$ is a Dirac measure $\mu=\delta_z$ for some $z\in E$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Thanks. Apparently, I skimmed your post too quickly.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: So, is it okay now?

Answer (score 1):

So as I showed in our discussion and function of form
$$ f(y) = 1 \wedge d(y,x)$$
would prove the implication (2) --->(1).
Now for your second statement, we can do as follows:

#### Main reply

Let
$$S =\{ x_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
Firstly, if $(x_n)$ admit a convergent subsequence with a limit $x$, our question is done. 
So assume there is no such property, then $\overline{S}=S $ and $(x_n)$ seperating

Now, let's consider the following function :
$$ g(y)= 1 \wedge d( y, \overline{S})$$

So as we know, this function is bounded and continuous.Morever :
$$g(y)=0 \quad \iff \quad y \in \overline{S}$$
Thus we imply that $supp(\mu) \subset \overline{S}=S$
Thus $\mu$ must have the following form:
$$ \mu = \lambda_1 \delta_{x_1}+\lambda_2 \delta_{x_1}+...$$
Where $(\lambda_n)$ is a nonnegative real sequence such that $ \sum_n \lambda_n=1$

Using the separation of $(x_n)$ to construct some functions to show that $$\lambda_n=0 \quad \forall n$$ Therefore,  our conclusion

$\square$

**Comments**

- I hope this one solution does not have any error.
- Perhaps, ( if mine is true), there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's clear to me that the claim follows if $S=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has a convergent subsequence. But if we assume that $S$ has no convergent subsequence, why does it follow that $\overline S=S$? And what do you mean by "$S$ is separating"? What does "separating" mean here?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Hi 0x, concerning your first question,  any point in $\overline{S}\S$ is, by definition, a limit point of $S$ hence if $\overline{S}\S$ is not empty,  we can construct a convergent subsequence for $(x_n)$ (by the definition of a limit point)

Comment: About the second question, by "separating", I mean for any point $x_n$ in $S$, I can find an open set $U_n$, say a ball, such that $U_n \cap S = \{x_n\}$. This is true because if this not happen for any point $x_N \in S$, we can construct a sequence of elements in $S$ (which are distinct from $x_N$) that converges to $x_N$. Hence the contradiction.

Comment: Oops, you've simply used the fact that $\overline S=S\cup\left\{\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k}:(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb N\text{ is increasing and }(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb N}\text{ is convergent}\right\}$, right?

Comment: Yeah, it is :) .

Comment: Thanks. Did you use that $C_b(E)$ is separating in order to conclude that $S$ has no convergent subsequence? If that's the case, please note that I think this is only correct when $E$ is complete and separable. Otherwise, which argument did you use?

Comment: I just need $(x_n)$ separating amongst themself.  To be more precise, I use the following argument . For any $N>0$, let $\epsilon_N$ be the positive real number such that $$B(x_N, \epsilon_N) \cap S = \{x_N\}$$  Let $$g(y)= (1-y)$$. We define $$f_N(x)= g(  (d(x,x_N)/\epsilon_N)\wedge 1 )$$  So for all $n>N$  , $f_N(x_n)=0$ , from which we imply $$\lambda_N=0$$ P/s: Sorry if I was not explicit in my proof because I deemed this part a little messy and I don't like it very much.

Comment: (a) Isn't your last comment devoted to the last part of your proof? I actually wanted know what your argument was to conclude the first part ("Firstly, if $(x_n)$ admit a convergent subsequence with a limit $x$, our question is done."). I thought you might have concluded this by the argument I gave in the question. (b) In your last comment, something went wrong in your definition of $g$. How did you intend to define it?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Do you mind showing me what's wrong with $g$?

Comment: For your first question, isn't it obvious? If such a thing happens, that means for all bounded continuous function $f$, we have: $$ f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$$. Hence $$x_n \rightarrow x$$

Comment: Sorry, it was late yesterday. $g$ is fine. But I don't understand your last comment. What we need to show in the first step is that if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has a convergent subsequence, then there is a $x\in E$ with $\mu=\delta_x$. Now, if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has a convergent subsequence, then $x_{n_k}\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}x$ for some increasing $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathbb N$ and some $x\in E$. By assumption, $\delta_{x_n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\mu$ weakly and hence $\delta_xf=\lim_{k\to\infty}\delta_{x_{n_k}}f=\mu f$ for all $f\in C_b(E)$.

Comment: Now how do you conclude $\mu=\delta_x$ (without using that $C_b(E)$ is separating)?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. So what's your definition of "separating".  On one hand, if it is in Weierstrass's theorem sense, then the fact that  $E$ is a metric space makes $C_b(E)$ separating ( for any two points $x,y$, the function  $g(z):= 1\wedge ( d(z,y) )$ separates $x$ and $y$ )

Comment: On the other hand, you see, the sequence $(f(x_n), n \ge 0 )$  is a real sequence which is convergent and also has $f(x)$ as a cluster point, so that makes $$f(x_n) \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow +\infty} f(x)$$ And as $E$ is a metric space, $\delta_{x}$ is a valid measure.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Hmmm, so you still follow this topic?

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply, but I didn't had the chance to come back to this problem until now. I say that a class $\mathcal C\subseteq C_b(E)$ is separating for a family $\mathcal F$ of finite signed measures on $\mathcal B(E)$ if $$\forall\mu,\nu\in\mathcal F:(\forall g\in\mathcal C:\mu g=\nu g)\Rightarrow\mu=\nu.$$ Now we can show that if $\mathcal C$ is a point-separating (in the sense you've mentioned) subalgebra of $C_b(E)$ with $1\in\mathcal C$, then $\mathcal C$ is separating for all **tight** finite signed measures on $\mathcal B(E)$.

Comment: So, in particular, $C_b(E)$ is "only" separating for the **tight** finite signed measures on $\mathcal B(E)$. (A finite signed measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal B(E)$ is called tight if for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is a compact $K\subseteq E$ with $|\mu|(K^c)<\varepsilon$.) Every Dirac measure is clearly tight, but unless you assume that $\mu$ is tight (which is always the case whenever $E$ is separable and complete), I don't know how you conclude $\mu=\delta_x$ from knowing that $\mu f=\delta_x$ for all $f\in C_b(E)$.

Comment: You have shown how impolite and arrogant you are. and this reply is my last bit of politeness. For any $\epsilon >0$, just construct a positive function $f$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1$ when $d(x,y)\ge \epsilon$. The rest is trivial. Remark: If you do care about the question of sign, positive, tight, etc, just reread your question.